# Inverse Fourier transform of $(\arctan(ak))^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> I was wondering how I can find the inverse Fourier transform of $(\arctan(ak))^{n}$. There isn't anything quite similar to this in the table of Fourier transforms that I have seen, and I am not quite sure how to do it. Also, I don't want to use the expansion of inverse tangent function.

Any help is appreciated.